# Why do they scan boarding passes two times at security control in Brussels airport (BRU)?

Tags: tickets, airport-security, bru

At Brussels airport they have electronical gates that will only let you through if you scan a valid boarding pass. After the gates, you go immediately to stand in line for security control. In that line, you have to show your boarding pass to a person who scans it with a handheld device.

I have not experienced this in any other airport, yet is has happened every single time at BRU, for the three years I've been coming there. Why do they have a person check exactly what the machine did, directly before? It seems like a very unnecessary waste of work.

Comment: At what point to you get the second scan? Just as you enter the line, or when you reach the actually security check? If the latter, then it's probably used for statistics on the number of people currently in line and the waiting time (in some airports the information in shown to passengers on screens).

Comment: It used to be that you had to scan the boarding pass at a reader next to the conveyor belt at each security lane. That was quite a hassle, as I am at that point usually busy moving stuff from trouser to coat. pockets, getting my laptop out etc... Having to jugle your boarding pass at that time was cumbersome.
They changed it now, but I still do not get the point.

Comment: I've seen this many times at many airports (even 3 times).  Seems pretty unremarkable.

Comment: Same happens at Gatwick too. In total 3 times i.e. before security, entering the departure gates area, then again before boarding.

Comment: The second scan happens about in the middle of the line for security. If the line is short, the second check happens with almost no time delay from the first. If the line is long, the second check occurrs a little after the first.